# How to add some items to the menu based on the role of user in ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, html, css

I am developing ASP.NET web application for my company. I am using the Windows Authentication since this web application will be only used inside the company.

I defined the menu/ navigation bar inside the site.master page as following:

```
<ul>
```

Home

Services

- Service 1
- Service 2
- Service 3

Portfolio

About Us

Also, I have two CSS files; one for the whole website and the other one for the menu.

Now, for the Admin, I want him to see the same menu bar but with more items. My friend told me that I can do this by implementing the menu as a user control since I have special CSS file for the menu. And you will be able to customize based on the role of the user.

So how can I do that? 
Please provide me with example (if any)

Answer (score 3):

Use the sitemap to define your menu list. With this you can define which role can see which link. My site map:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<siteMap xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/AspNet/SiteMap-File-1.0" >
  <siteMapNode url="Default.aspx" title="Home Page"  description="">
    <siteMapNode url="Merchant/Default.aspx" title="Merchant"  description="">
      <siteMapNode url="Merchant/ProdcutManager.aspx" roles="Merchant" title="Product Manager"></siteMapNode>
      <siteMapNode url="Merchant/PromotionManager.aspx" roles="Merchant" title="Promotion Manager"></siteMapNode>
      <siteMapNode url="Merchant/AccountManager.aspx" roles="Merchant" title="Account Manager"></siteMapNode>
    </siteMapNode>
    <siteMapNode url="Customer/Default.aspx" title="Customer"  description="">
      <siteMapNode url="Customer/AccountManager.aspx" roles="Customer" title="Account Manager"></siteMapNode>
      <siteMapNode url="Customer/Transfer.aspx" roles="Customer" title="Points transfer"></siteMapNode>
    </siteMapNode>
  </siteMapNode>
</siteMap>
```

Then use asp:menu to render the menu with site map datasource.